# Difficulty in filling the screen by ad in landscape mode

Tags: android

I am using an ad in my application.It works fine when the emulator works in portrait mode but when i turn the emulator to the landscape mode,it does fill the horizontal screen even when i have given the android:layout_width="match_parent". Please tell me how to solve this problem.

This is the xml file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:id="@+id/rl"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        />

     <com.google.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/ad"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="a1501e5633125fb"
        ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
        ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR, 123456789ABCDEF" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I think they don't fill screen horizontally. Never saw any AdMob banner horizontally filled in landscape mode like games in AngryBirds.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use [Smart Banner](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/smart-banners) for that.

Smart Banners are new ad units (as of v6.0.0) that will render screen-wide banner ads on any screen size across different devices in either orientation. Smart Banners help deal with increasing screen fragmentation across different devices by "smartly" detecting the width of the phone in its current orientation, and making the ad view that size.

Comment: I am not understanding sir.Please give some example.

Comment: @user1551338: use ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER" .